# $ \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2 (kx)}{k}$ and $ \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos^2 (kx)}{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Let's examine the series $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\sin^2 (kx)}{k}$ and  $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\cos^2 (kx)}{k}$

---

My attempt :

$\forall t , ~ \cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t) =1$ and $\sum\limits_{k \ge 1} \dfrac{1}{k} =\infty$ . 
As the two terms are positives, at least one of the series should be divergent.
How to prove that both series are divergent ?

As given in hint, $\cos^2(kx)= 1 + 2 \cos(2kx)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Both series diverge.  To show this, make use of the identities

$$\begin{align}
\sin^2(x)&=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\\\\
\cos^2(x)&=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}
\end{align}$$

along with the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}$ converges for $x\ne m\pi$, $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, as guaranteed by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Statement).

Comment: The diference has a general term $\frac{cos(kx)}{k}$ that diverges. The sum  is a serie that diverges.

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\cos^2(nx)}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{1+\cos(2nx)}{n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n +\frac12\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}$$The harmonic series diverges, but $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}$ converges when $x\ne m \pi$.  What does that tell you about the original series?

Comment: The sum of one serie converges and one serie diverges, diverges. So the original serie diverges.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  You have it now.  Well done.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do the Dirichlet's test.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.