# $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{ \mid sin (kx) \mid}{k}$

Tags: divergent-series

What is the nature of :
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{ \mid sin (kx) \mid}{k}$$

We know that :

1. $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{  sin (kx)}{k}$  converges with Dirichlet test [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046026/prove-sum-k-1-infty-frac-sinkxk-converges)
2. $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{  sin ^2(kx)}{k}$  diverges [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795262/sum-k-1-infty-dfrac-sin2-kxk-and-sum-k-1-infty-dfrac)
3. $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{  sin ^2(kx)}{k^2}$  converges

Comment: Your are done and must done.${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we have $\sin(kx)^2\le|\sin(kx)|$ (Why ?)

So $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{ \mid \sin (kx) \mid}{k} \ge \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{ \sin (kx)^2}{k}$ which, I think, concludes on the divergence.

Comment: Thanks, I try with $k$ and $k^2$.